# android eclipse splash screen image not showing

Tags: android, eclipse, splash-screen

i created a splash screen but when i launch my app the splash screen does not show, just a black screen. however, after my timer for the splash screen ends, my menu comes up. in the graphical layout of my splashscreen.xml, the splash screen image show. but when run, it does not. all is normal except for my splash screen...

code for myMain.java:

```
package com.immrroj.firstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class myMain extends Activity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    Thread splashtimer = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                int timer = 0;
                while (timer < 5000)
                {
                    sleep(100);
                    timer = timer + 100;
                }
                startActivity(new Intent("com.immrroj.firstapp.CLEARSCREEN"));
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally
            {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    splashtimer.run();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
}

}
```

code for myMenu.java

```
package com.immrroj.firstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class myMenu extends Activity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

}
```

code for my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/mymenu">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PRESS ME!!"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:width="200dp" android:layout_gravity="right"/>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="PRESS ME TOO!" 
     android:gravity="center" 
     android:textSize="19dp" 
     android:textStyle="bold" android:width="200dp" android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

code for my splashscreen.xml.... the image androidsplash is not showing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/androidsplash"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

code for my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.immrroj.firstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".myMain" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".myMenu" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.immrroj.firstapp.CLEARSCREEN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

please help..although i can continue, it is really bugging me....

UPDATE:
okay... i think its really hard to fix this without having hands on the code... so im posting this link so  anybody can see the codes and tinker it... please help me... i wnat to learn android but im stuck in here.... download source code here, it's safe i swear: https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=79ecba5b079a1b4c&resid=79ECBA5B079A1B4C!293&parid=79ECBA5B079A1B4C!113&authkey=!AK8-cta_tThQUms

Comment: Can you put `TextView` with some text into your splash xml layout? My guess would be that its your image that is not being shown.

Comment: i removed first the image and put a textview... however, the text is also not showing during the splash screen loading.... T T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

Downloaded your .rar and gave it a look. Turns out there was something wrong with your `Thread`. I don't know exactly what, but it was causing the layout not to be properly loaded (probably because you made it sleep for 100 ms, then wake up, check a variable, and sleep again for 100 ms over and over).

I changed your thread with the following code and now it works perfectly on my phone:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            // Thread to show the splash screen, then launch the main screen
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(2500); // set this to how long you want to wait before
                                    // showing the main screen
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent mainScreen = new Intent(
                            "com.immrroj.firstapp.CLEARSCREEN");
                    startActivity(mainScreen);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
```

You can leave all the other `onStart, onPause etc` methods out, you're not using those in a splash screen anyway.

I uploaded the edited code here: [Download](http://www.mediafire.com/?k7ajd9undwyyrun)

Good luck with your app!

Comment: If you remove the timer, and all the onStop etc methods, only leaving the basic `onCreate` and `setContentView`, does it work then?

Since it's just a splash screen you don't need all the other `on...` methods.

Comment: Wow that's really odd. But you said you can see the image in the gui designer right? Did you change the image with a different one recently by any chance? If so, open your app's folder in your workspace, and delete the /bin folder. After that, rebuild your app.  I had sort-off the same problem recently due to a cached image problem. I replaced all my images but I was never able to see them, they were just not showing up on the emulator / my phone, but I could see them in the graphical layout editor.

Comment: i did not change the images recently... can you please take a look in the project... the link to the original files are posted above, at the end of my question... dont worry, its safe... just please take a look at my code and tell me what's wrong... im a newbie so i might have put things in the code that ruined it

Comment: Done. I downloaded your files and fixed the problem. I edited my answer with the correct one. Good luck!